# Using functions with blank parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, class

I'm doing the code academy JS course, and sometimes I find it confusing to know when to pass arguments into a function, and when to leave it blank.

For example, when creating a new class, I'll use a function with arguments:

```
function Person (name, age, address, email) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.address = address;
this.email = email;
} 

var zach = new Person ('Zach', '30', 'Bla Bla', 'email@gmail.com);
```

but sometimes, I see classes created with blank arguments, such as this:

```
function StudentReport() {
this.grade1 = 4;
this.grade2 = 2;
this.grade3 = 1;
this.getGPA = function() {
    return (this.grade1 + this.grade2 + this.grade3) / 3;
};
}
```

How do you know when to use a function that takes arguments, and when to use one that doesn't? My initial thought is that you do this whenever you give a value to your properties (In this case each grade as a numeric value).

Am I right?
Thanks

Comment: Actually we pass parameters into a function and those parameters become arguments within the function when it is called, But to answer the question, we pass parameters to constructor functions when we're going to do something with them inside the function: assigning a variable/property, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

First don't confuse parameters with arguments, **parameters** are what are defined in the function definition, **arguments** are what are passed in when the function is called.

```
function Person (name, age, address, email)
```

name, age, address, and email here are **parameters**

When the function is called,

```
var zach = new Person ('Zach', '30', 'Bla Bla', 'email@gmail.com);
```

'Zach', '30', 'Bla Bla', and 'email@gmail.com' are the **arguments** being passed to the function.

As far as when to use functions with parameters, a short answer would be:

If you plan to reuse the function with different values (arguments), then define a function with parameters, otherwise you would have to recreate the entire function with the new values every time.

If you are only using the function one time to set some values, or perform some other action(s). Then a function without parameters will do just fine.

Comment: It was a bit hard to give one answer to the question as it is too broad IMO but this answer is a good one ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I struggled a little to make a concise answer. We could obviously spend much time discussing this topic, but I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks, so in other words, a function that takes parameters is one that is going to be reused for a few times. And a function that doesn't take parameters is one that does more of a general action (In this case a hard set calculation) once without needing to change it?

Comment: Yes, that is a pretty good general rule. Check out Code School's JavaScript road trip, it does a pretty good job of explaining many of the basic concepts of JavaScript in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand that in functions are originally borrowed from mathematics.

a function is a procedure that takes input of type A and returns an output of type B, while A and B can be almost anything.

an example is the addition function which basically takes 2 arguments that are numeric, and returns a single result which is also numeric. so let all numbers be called A, the addition function is henceforth AXA -> A.

other examples:

absolute value function : number -> number
the javascript `console.log` function(prints to console) : string -> (nothing)

the javascript parseInt function(turns string to number) : string -> number

the javascript location.reload function(refresh tab) : (nothing) -> (nothing)

with the explanation above, let us understand the meaning of using parameters. 
the parameters you use are your way to define what the function will take in order to return something. 
your Person function is meant to take name, age, addres etc. in order to return a person object. If that function was supposed to always return the same person, then you wouldn't need any of them since you could have known them beforehand.

Thus, parameters are used in order to involve additional information, additional input that your function needs in order to return the wanted result. use it when you want to customize the behavior of your function, when you don't need to,
like in `reload`, then don't.